# What code do I use to automatically Save As that references a file path in the sheet the macro is stored?

Tags: excel, vba

```
**ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Sheets.(Sheet1).Range("B25")**
```

Cell ("B25") is equal to W:356487\Desktop\ExcelFiles\ABCtemplate.xlsb

The Save As portion is located at the end of my macro once the code has finished running.

Answer (score 0):

```
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=range("b25").value, _ FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
```

Comment: you may have to mess around with the file format, but i'd suggest recording a macro and looking at the code after you save it

Comment: I have no idea as to how I would even record that @jellz77

Comment: also, your sheet reference is invalid in your original post.  when referencing a sheet you want to use `sheets("Sheet1").range("b25").value`

Comment: http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-record-a-macro-to-automate-tasks-in-excel-2.html

Comment: it brought back an error saying the file did not exist

Comment: your file path is missing a back slash `W:\356487\Desktop\ExcelFiles\ABCtemplate.xlsb`

Comment: Still an error saying the file does not exist...is it because it is not recognizing the last part? Otherwise I have no idea as to how to make it save to that exact file path with that same name ABCtemplate.xlsb

Comment: can you try saving to the `c:` drive (if you have access...not sure if you're at work)

Comment: is `w:` a server path?

Comment: it is my shared drive

Comment: also change your file format to `xlExcel12` if xlsb

Comment: @JHags please mark your answer as solved if you were able to use this (or any other answer) as a resolution. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There was some syntax issues in your line, corrected below: -

```
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B25")
```

Also ensure that the path in B25 points to an existing folder.

Comment: I want to save the file as that name.xlsb in the file path which is in B25, but for some reason it still brings about an error